# Applet not showing image

Tags: java, applet

I was following this tutorial [here](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-4-enter-the-robot.html)

and I downloaded its source code and ran but the image is not showing.

here is the result 
[image]

I was expecting that the result would be like this
[image]
same as the result in the tutorial.

Here is the code:
StartingClass.java

```
package kiloboltgame;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.net.URL;

public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    private Robot robot;
    private Image image, character;
    private Graphics second;
    private URL base;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        setSize(800, 480);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("Q-Bot Alpha");
        try {
            base = getDocumentBase();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        // Image Setups
        character = getImage(base, "data/character.png");
        System.out.println(" "+base);

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        robot = new Robot();

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            robot.update();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            second = image.getGraphics();
        }

        second.setColor(getBackground());
        second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        second.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(second);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(character, robot.getCenterX() - 61, robot.getCenterY() - 63, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            System.out.println("Move up");
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            System.out.println("Move down");
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            robot.moveLeft();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            robot.moveRight();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            System.out.println("Jump");
            robot.jump();
            break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            System.out.println("Stop moving up");
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            System.out.println("Stop moving down");
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            robot.stop();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            robot.stop();
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            System.out.println("Stop jumping");
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Robot.java

```
package kiloboltgame;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Robot {

    private int centerX = 100;
    private int centerY = 382;
    private boolean jumped = false;

    private int speedX = 0;
    private int speedY = 1;


    public void update() {

        // Moves Character or Scrolls Background accordingly.
        if (speedX < 0) {
            centerX += speedX;
        } else if (speedX == 0) {
            //System.out.println("Do not scroll the background.");

        } else {
            if (centerX <= 150) {
                centerX += speedX;
            } else {
                //System.out.println("Scroll Background Here");
            }
        }

        // Updates Y Position
        centerY += speedY;
        if (centerY + speedY >= 382) {
            centerY = 382;
        }

        // Handles Jumping
        if (jumped == true) {
            speedY += 1;

            if (centerY + speedY >= 382) {
                centerY = 382;
                speedY = 0;
                jumped = false;
            }

        }

        // Prevents going beyond X coordinate of 0
        if (centerX + speedX <= 60) {
            centerX = 61;
        }
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        speedX = 6;
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        speedX = -6;
    }

    public void stop() {
        speedX = 0;
    }

    public void jump() {
        if (jumped == false) {
            speedY = -15;
            jumped = true;
        }

    }

    public int getCenterX() {
        return centerX;
    }

    public int getCenterY() {
        return centerY;
    }

    public boolean isJumped() {
        return jumped;
    }

    public int getSpeedX() {
        return speedX;
    }

    public int getSpeedY() {
        return speedY;
    }

    public void setCenterX(int centerX) {
        this.centerX = centerX;
    }

    public void setCenterY(int centerY) {
        this.centerY = centerY;
    }

    public void setJumped(boolean jumped) {
        this.jumped = jumped;
    }

    public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
        this.speedX = speedX;
    }

    public void setSpeedY(int speedY) {
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }

}
```

and here is my file structure in intelij

[image]

Whats wrong with the code?? I tride the "../data/character.png" and "../src/data/character.png" but it didnt work.

Comment: Instead of learning AWT, why don't you learn Swing? You can start with the Swing tutorial on [How to Make an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html).

Comment: I dont see much difference between using awt and swing. As my objective was to have a basic understanding on how game development works ^^

Comment: There is a big difference. Painting is done differently, you use different components.

Comment: (off topic) May i know what's your ide? The ui looks good.

Comment: @Drogba im using intellij 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `applet.html` the page loading the applet.
- `data` (directory)

  - `Character.png`

If that is the structure of the **server**, the image will be available by:

```
getImage(base, "data/character.png");
```

I stressed **server** above since that is apparently not how your IDE is set up.

---

> Can you elaborate more?

[image]

You opened the `src/kilobolt` path to show the locations of the source files, but it you expand the `bin` folder and trace down, you'll probably find the `.class` files in the `bin/kilobolt` directory.

An IDE typically won't use an HTML file for loading the applet, but if IntelliJ did, it would probably put it in the `bin` directory so it has direct access to the class files.
The path from there to the image would be `../data/character.png`, but instead of using that path,  suggest you get the IDE to copy the image into the `bin`.

At this stage it has become about IntelliJ so any further questions you have, will need to be about the IDE and the run-time class-path it uses.

Comment: Can u elaborate more? I also tried it in eclipse but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an image issue. The computer is not able to find the location of the image, or the image is being drawn under the applet.

IF you are using a linux/Mac/unix machine, most of time, I have had to either start from the root folder such as /Users/.....to the source folder, or when using a directory that is closer, just use '/' in front of it. Example is:

You're using a directory named src, with an 'img' folder inside. To get to the 'img' contents, you have two options:

//......src/img

or

/src/img/....

Hope that helped with anything

Answer (score 0):

**Copy your data folder into the bin folder. 
Clean the project and run.**

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

@Luiggi Mendoza I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by right clicking on 'character.png' and selecting properties and then copying the image's location all the way from its root. In my case it was "/Users/macbookpro/NetBeansProjects/Kilobolt/src/data/character.png" and bingo the robot appeared in the applet window.

And yeah, i am learning game from the same website as you were 3 years back