# After inserting an image -> the Applet stop to work (there is just a gray box)

Tags: java, firefox, netbeans, applet

I read already a lot of topics like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121885/applet-stops-at-applet-loaded-and-displays-nothing-works-perfectly-on-bluej-a) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270823/applet-not-showing-image) on stack overflow without no luck.
So what is going on. I have an applet that I created in Netbeans. It works fine until I insert an image in it as icon. My os is MAC and I use Firefox.
In Netbeans the applet looks ok when I run it. The problem is that in Firefox I see just a gray BOX instead of my applet.
Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: *"Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?"*  There is a problem in the code or file locations, or maybe other things. To start with 1) Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Show the location of the HTML, applet (class/jar) & image.  3) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is showing, and copy/paste paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

So my HTML file looks like that:

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>Applet HTML Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

<P>
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="slipapplet/SlipApplet.class" width=880 height=650 archive="/Users/Serial/NetBeansProjects/SlipApplet/build/classes/slipapplet/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar,/Users/Serial/NetBeansProjects/SlipApplet/build/classes/slipapplet/AbsoluteLayout.jar"></APPLET>
</P>

<HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is code about the label with icon in java:

jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Users/Serial/NetBeansProjects/SlipApplet/src/slipapplet/kemp.jpg")));

And the HTML file is in an upper file then everything else..