# Image doesn't appear in applet

Tags: java, applet

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270823/applet-not-showing-image?rq=1) post suggests that it is an IDE specific problem, but the solution given is for IntelliJ. I'm using Eclipse.

I'm following [this](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-4-enter-the-robot.html) guide about game programming in Android. But before that it teaches about game programming in Java.

When I try to load an image in the applet as specified on the guide, nothing is shown, just the black background. My source code and the web's one are almost identical, how can I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
package game;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.net.URL;

public class Incio extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

private Robot robot;
private Image image, character;
private Graphics second;
private URL base;

@Override
public void init() {
    setSize(800, 480);
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setFocusable(true);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("LAS AVENTURAS DE RABOCOP");
    addKeyListener(this);
    robot = new Robot();
    try {
        base = getDocumentBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        }
    character = getImage(base, "/src/data/Robot.bmp");
    System.out.println(base);
}

@Override
public void start() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
    switch (k.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        break;

    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
    switch (k.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        break;

    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (true) {

        robot.update();
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void update(Graphics g) {
    if (image == null) {
        image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        second = image.getGraphics();
    }

    second.setColor(getBackground());
    second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    second.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(second);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(character, robot.getCenterX()-61, robot.getCenterY()-63, this);
}
}
```

Thanks.